# How to run function dynamically in golang?

Tags: go

How internally play.golang.org compiles and run the go code?

I have a function as string. I need to check the syntax and run the code inside golang main function.

Comment: For playground internals, see: https://blog.golang.org/playground. Otherwise, if you want to run Go code, compile and run the Go code.

Answer (score 4):

The code is sent to a server to be compiled and executed then the output is sent back to the client (the browser).

There is an article on how it works : https://blog.golang.org/playground

Answer (score 1):

Go code is a bit hard to run dynamically. You can "check" the syntax with the [parser](https://golang.org/pkg/go/parser/) package, although using those packages under `go` can be a bit tricky. To actually run it, you would likely need to:

1. Save the function to a temporary directory, possibly generating a `main` to invoke it.
2. exec the go compiler to generate an executable
3. Run the compiled binary, possibly piping stdin and stdout to the parent process.
4. Communicate with it over stdin/stdout until it exits

This is obviously a big runaround and quite a pain.

If go is not strictly required there are multiple [scripting languages](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#embeddable-scripting-languages) with go implementations. If you supply javascript or lua or whatever code, you can run that dynamically.

Comment: Incidentally, for an example of how to do this, check out the mockgen portion of Gomock: https://github.com/golang/mock/tree/master/mockgen.  That's exactly how that library generates mocks, it creates a new go program using templates, then compiles and executes it to generate the actual mock code.

Comment: Which one is faster in execution? Whether scripting language or create, compile and run the golang?

Comment: Without details of your use case, it is hard to say. The compiling option is going to have a longer time to start up, but may run faster. If it matters, benchmark it.