# How to run go code dynamically from string?

Tags: go

I need to execute code dynamically, for example to run `fmt.Print("hello")` (in string format), maybe what I am looking for is a go virtual machine?

With go-playground, we can type the code and execute it, how does that work behind?

The worst solution would be to write string code to a file and call it with `exec.Command("go", "run","file")`.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44139161/13075) partially answers your question.

Comment: Your "worst solution" is _exactly_ what the Go playground does because it is basically the _only_ way to do it. For simple thing a Go interpreter might fit your need (google "golang interpreter" and pick any). There is no direct way to "eval" Go code in the stdlib.

Comment: Go is a compiled language, not an interpreted language. There is no native support for executing arbitrary strings as Go code; executing any Go code with the standard SDK requires writing it to a file, compiling it to a binary, and executing that binary.

Comment: Hi @seaguest, have you looked at https://github.com/containous/yaegi ?

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Playground

> With go-playground, we can type the code and execute it, how does that work behind?

I suppose that you answered your owm question in most part.

It does not take long to find  source of [compileAndRun](https://github.com/golang/playground/blob/509e10fc018f6da63e433d45afbf5c21af9480a2/sandbox.go#L306) from playground.

> The worst solution would be to write string code to a file and call it with exec.Command("go", "run","file").

And yes, it uses:
https://github.com/golang/playground/blob/509e10fc018f6da63e433d45afbf5c21af9480a2/sandbox.go#L361

```golang
    cmd := exec.Command("go", "build", "-o", exe, buildPkgArg)
```

## 2. Jupyter kernels, gore, lgo, gophernotes and gomacro

Although it does not means that it must be always this way.

I myself plan to look in spare time into:

- gophernotes
- lgo
- and [gomacro](https://github.com/cosmos72/gomacro) which itself is package used for gophernotes

Overall: it's not that easy as `eval` in other languages but nothing stops to implement it.

Good luck!